# $facebook->getUser when user is using FB as a page

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-iframe, facebook-page, facebook-canvas

OK, so my application works fine and dandy, but I recently discovered a problem when a user is logged in "as a page".  When the user is logged in as a page and goes directly to the app base url... i.e. *apps.facebook.com/...* it correctly identifies that the user object is incorrect and sends the user to:

```
https://www.facebook.com/login/roadblock.php?target_url=...
```

This makes the user login as the actual FB user, and it works well.

But it does not do this on the app's page tab.  It just redirects to:

```
https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/platform/page_proxy.php?v=4
```

Is there a command or function in the PHP SDK that can check if the user is using as a page, and redirect them to the referred page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know a user switch the their account to use as page account?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8633979/how-to-know-a-user-switch-the-their-account-to-use-as-page-account)

Comment: OK, but then how does FB determine the user is using as page and redirect to roadblock?  Something fires on the full app page that doesn't when on the same app's page tab...

Comment: It's doesn't really matter how Facebook determinate this, that information never passed to your application, so this is a show stopper. The best you can do is file a bug using [Bug Tool](developers.facebook.com/bugs/create) and see what officials say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to check if user logged in as page due to fact that Facebook doesn't provide this information and prompting to switch back to usage of regular Facebook account on any interaction with applications.